# PowerShell : binding existing certificate in resource group

Tags: azure, powershell, ssl

Im trying to bind an exisiting certificate in the resource group in a custom domain.

`New-AzWebAppSSLBinding -ResourceGroupName $webappname -WebAppName $webappname -Thumbprint "$newthumbprint" -Name "$customdomain"`

When I Debug this the custom domain isn't found, But when I check the domain in microsoft azure under tls/ssl bindings, the domain is there with his old thumbprint.

When im using the original domain of the webapp (.azurewebsites.net) then it would say that there is a conflict because in the new certificate is that domain not registered and thats good because I dont want that.

Anyone know how I can change the thumbprint of customdomains in powershell instead of waste my time in microsoft azure application and doing it more then 100 times manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the error, "custom domain isn't found" or  "Hostname 'www.exmaple.com' does not exist", here are possible reasons:

- You could check the **certificate's subject name** must match the **domains** used to access the Web App.

[image]

- You should find the existing certificate under **TLS/SSL settings**---**Private Key Certificates**. When you run the PowerShell commands, ensure that you type the correct Hostname and matched Thumbprint.

[image]

The command is working well on my side.

[image]

In addition, If you update an SSL certificate from a local machine to the Azure web app, you can use this command.

```
New-AzWebAppSSLBinding -ResourceGroupName $webapprg -WebAppName $webappname -CertificateFilePath $PathToPfxFile -CertificatePassword $PlainTextPwd -Name $customdomain
```

Comment: In the custom domains I see the assigned custom domains (that im using in the powershell script) also on TLS/SSL I would see here the hostnames.

Comment: What's the SSL certificate you are using? Could you show the full scripts or screenshots about the error?

Comment: I think I see the problem, I just using the resourcegroup as the webappname and you using two different names.

I tried the name of the app service but then I cant find the azure web app...

Comment: You should use an app service name and resource group name that the web app belonged to . What do you mean `I cant find the azure web app`? Does the app service not exist on that resource group?

Comment: I toke this from the url

/resourceGroups/test-resource/
/sites/ucp-test-services/appServices

resourcegroup = test-resource
webappname = test-services

The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/test-services' under resource group 'test-resource' was not found

Comment: Try `Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName  test-resource | select name` to find the app service name in that resource group.

Comment: there is only one resource to find in this group called: test-resource

but in azure there are 67 resources find in this resource group...

Comment: Try `New-AzWebAppSSLBinding -ResourceGroupName test-resource -WebAppName ucp-test-services -Thumbprint $newthumbprint -Name $customdomain`? I see that url, the app service name is ucp-test-services. I has a bit confused about your providing info. Perhaps, you could show any screenshots?

Comment: cant find the service. its just only the resource group name. is it possible that I dont have enough permissions?

Comment: Do you have multiple subscriptions? Do you have log in with the correct account? do you see the app service in the resource group via Azure portal? sure, you also need enough permission to do it.

Comment: with ``Get-AzureADTenantDetail`` I see the correct directory

Comment: my permission role is contributor.

Comment: Try `Get-AzContext` to see the subscription and tenant info.

Comment: It stay on the wrong tenantId... 

I connect with ``Connect-AzureAD -TenantId 07****``
and the actually tenantId is 6101*******

Comment: You should use `Connect-AzAccount ` to connect to Azure account with selecting the expected tenant. Then run the above `New-AzWebAppSSLBinding` commands.

Comment: Wow thanks, now im on the correct one, only I only see one services, I think I need to ask more rights :p